# .NET Framework 4.6.2 Release DWORD different from Version REG_SZ

Tags: registry, .net-framework-version

Recently, I've been trying to install .NET Framework 4.6.2 using Ansible, on a Windows Server 2012 R2. To be sure that installation was completed successfully, I have checked the registries in order to find out the version of the installed package, but I have encountered a problem.

When accessing HLKM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full, I checked the following variables:

Version [REG_SZ]: 4.6.01590

Release [REG_DWORD]: 0x00060636 (**394806**)

I have searched a bit about Release variable [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/deployment-guide-for-developers#detect_net) (official microsoft docs) and the value it state that .NET Framework 4.6.2 is installed.

My question is it could be a bug in system and does not update the Version value even though .NET Framework 4.6.2 is installed?

EDIT @Hans Passant: I have done some research meanwhile about this difference between Version and Release on microsoft docs and I concluded that there is no problem indeed, Version is just incremented each time when a new release appear. More informations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies). Thank you also for clarification.

Comment: Not a bug, just too many version numbers.  01590 and 394806 are the kind of numbers that build engineers at Microsoft fret about, "4.6.2" is for normal people.  You don't have a problem.